# Powershell Script to remove US language via Intune

Tags: powershell, intune

This simple powershell script works when I run it manually but it refuses to work when deploying via Intune. It doesn't matter if I use Windows app (Win32) (with install.cmd) or Endpoint Windows PowerShell scripts. I tried running it as admin, running using User or System context. Nothing. I didn't find any errors on IntuneManagementExtension.log. I just want to remove the US language completely (around 100 Windows 10 Pro laptops - Powershell 5).

```
Import-Module -Name International (tested with and without this line)
$LangList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$MarkedLang = $LangList | Where-Object LanguageTag -eq "en-US"
$LangList.Remove($MarkedLang)
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-GB -Force
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error do you get? Whatever module you use has to be available on the endpoint, either copied ot the PSModulePath or installed using `Install-Module`

Comment: The script runs but the US language is not deleted. 

<![LOG[[PowerShell] Policy body = Import-Module -Name International
.....
Set-WinUserLanguageList en-GB -Force
, hash = LOG]!><time="15:25:18.2598154" date="8-26-2021" component="IntuneManagementExtension" context="" type="1" thread="30" file="">
...
<![LOG[Execution is done, collecting result]LOG]!><time="..." date="..." component="Intune Management" context="" type="1" thread="5" file="">
<![LOG[[PowerShell] User Id = .., Policy id = .. policy result = Success]